# Filter out records in specified day of week in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date, inner-query

I have inner query which is returning a specified date according to the date between condition. im successfully getting results but in outer query i want to check whether date is in the string i have provided ex-'Friday,Saturday'

```
SELECT * from 
    (
    SELECT id, to_char(markupdate, 'Day') as dayofweek 
    FROM test t 
    WHERE t.markupdate BETWEEN 'Thu Jul 11 00:00:00 IST 2019' AND 'Sat Jul 20 00:00:00 IST 2019'
    ) data
    WHERE data.dayofweek in ('Friday,Sunday');
```

Comment: Change to: `WHERE data.dayofweek in ('Friday', 'Sunday')`

Comment: tried! noting get displayed.

Comment: Try using a regular expression using `~`. See this link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-matching.html

Comment: It works yet i cannot include the array like ('Friday','Saturday'). for one day it works !

Comment: I was thinking something like: `data.dayofweek~'.*Friday.*' or data.dayofweek~'.*Sunday.*'`

Comment: You say: *im successfully getting results*. If you do and you get days like:  'Friday','Saturday','Sunday',........... then it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match your `data.dayofweek`to the Strings you are looking for (`Friday`, `Sunday`). You don't even need your subquery, something like that should also work:

```sql
 SELECT id, to_char(markupdate, 'Day') as dayofweek 
 FROM test t 
 WHERE t.markupdate BETWEEN '2019-07-11 00:00:00+0530' AND '2019-07-20 00:00:00+0530'
 AND dayofweek~'(Friday|Sunday)';
```

For more background infos check the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-matching.html).

Comment: I only see three problems with this. Unnecessary subquery, bad regexes, conversion to string based on presumed database locale. Otherwise, it technically works under some scenarios.

Comment: @coladict: Is it better like this now?

Comment: The regex is better, the ISO8601 dates are standard, so you don't even need `to_date`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, to_char(markupdate, 'Day') as dayofweek 
FROM test t 
WHERE t.markupdate BETWEEN 'Thu Jul 11 00:00:00 IST 2019' AND 'Sat Jul 20 00:00:00 IST 2019' 
AND date_part('dow', markupdate) in (5,0);
```

Week dates in postgres return values as follows:

```
0 Sunday
1 Monday
2 Tuesday
3 Wednesday
4 Thursday
5 Friday
6 Saturday
```

Instead of `date_part('dow', markupdate)` you can use the more standard SQL `EXTRACT('dow' FROM markupdate)`, but `dow` is an extension, not part of the SQL standard.

Comment: Also, you should use SQL-standard date formats. Instead of `'Thu Jul 11 00:00:00 IST 2019'` use `'2019-07-11 00:00:00+0530'`